# Is it possible to connect a Vin to a ref of an instrumentation amplifier?

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier, wheatstone-bridge

I have a circuit in which I need an instrumentation amplifier (INA128 ([datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina128.pdf))) to be connected correctly for it to work. I don't know if it needs another resistance or if the input needs to be connected to the Non-Inverting input. I would like to receive suggestions.

[image: instrumentation amplifier circuit]

Answer (score 1):

> it needs another resistance

Yes. With an INA the gain is set with an extra resistor:

[image]

3.3V is far too low for the [INA128](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina128.pdf) to work. Look how the output voltage is limited according to the gain and power supply:

[image]

A solution would to power the device with a symmetrical power supply (e.g. \$\pm 9V\$), with the 0V central reference connected to the microcontroller GND. Depending on the low pass filter, protection to the ADC input should also be added. A simple supply would be possible but would also limit the input voltage range of the ADC.

> Is it possible to connect a Vin to a ref

How 'ref' pin should be connected depends on how the bridge operates. It should guarantee, together with the gain, that the output voltage remains within the ADC specs. The final output voltage will be \$\left(DifferentialInputVoltage \times Gain\right) + V_{REF}\$

The shunt regulators/voltage references used in the bridges are not exactly the same. It seems 2.5V instead of 0.5V would be the choice if using them.